# IBM Watson for Oncology API

Tags: ibm-watson

I'll be short to save your time :)

I'm new at StackOverflow and also new with IBM Watson.

We are building an EMR (electronic medical records) system and would be glad to enhance it with Watson cognitive capabilities for healthcare.

**Where do I start from?**

Is here anyone who has ever used cognitive approach for assisted medical decision making? Can anyone give me an orientation?

I thought to start with Q&A for doctors but Q&A has been depreciated by IBM. Predictive analytics would also be exciting for physicians, however, what is the starting point?

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to a deprecated Bluemix API for health. One thing you can do is use Retrieve and Rank API on a trusted set of documents.

Answer (score 0):

yes I have used the following for health with IBM Watson

1. Reading chest X-rays - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/
2. Reading EKG's - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/
3. Patient diagnosis for chest pain - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/dialog.html
4. Physical exam - we started to use retrieve and rank for machine learning of a patient's physical exam over the years. - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-rank.html
5. Speech to text (patient telling watson where it hurts) - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text.html

As you can see there are many different watson api's .